# React - buggy issues with my simple radio button component placed on css grid

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-grid, react-bootstrap

I am building my first react app, and an important component for my application is an aesthetic set of radio buttons, that will be used on most of my apps pages, whose values are used to filter data of mine that is being graphed. To make the component simpler for me to make, I decided to use react-bootstrap's ToggleButton and ToggleButtonGroup components, and then create my presentational component **ToolButtonGroup** as sort of a wrapper around the react-bootstrap components.

What I have so far for **ToolButtonGroup.js**:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { ToggleButton, ToggleButtonGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';

class ToolButtonGroup extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    handleChartTypeChange = (e) => {
        this.props.handler();
    }

    render() {

        // Get Variables from the params prop
        const { header, buttons, initialVal } = this.props.params;
        const { borderRadius, margin, padding, fontsize, border } = this.props.params;
        const { gridID, gridColumns, minRowHeight } = this.props.params;

        // Create the individual buttons
        const pageButtons = buttons.map((buttoninfo, idx) => {
            return (
                <ToggleButton 
                    key={idx}
                    style={{
                        "borderRadius": borderRadius, 
                        "margin": margin,
                        "padding": padding,
                        "fontSize": fontsize,
                        "border": border
                    }}
                    bsSize="large"
                    value={buttoninfo.value}>
                {buttoninfo.label}
                </ToggleButton>
            )
        })

        // Return the button group
        return(
            <div className="buttons-container"
                 style={{"border": "1px solid red";}}
                 id={gridID}>
                <h2 style={{
                  "width": "100%";
                  "margin": "0 auto";
                  "fontSize": "1.75em";
                  "marginTop": "5px";   
                  "border": "none";
                }}
                >{header}</h2>
                <ToggleButtonGroup 
                    type="radio"
                    name="charttype-options" 
                    defaultValue={initialVal} 
                    onChange={this.props.handler}
                    style={{
                        "display": "grid",
                        "gridTemplateColumns": "repeat(" + gridColumns + ", 1fr)",
                        "gridAutoRows": "auto",
                        "gridGap": "8px"
                    }}
                >
                    {pageButtons}
                </ToggleButtonGroup>
            </div>
        )
    }   
}

export default ToolButtonGroup;
```

I used the parameters passed to this component to make a css grid of ToggleButtons in a ToggleButtonGroup. The data / initial value for the buttons, much of the styling, and also the grid data is all coming in as props from a parent component.

*(I'm actually not sure if using the react-bootstrap components made making this component easier or harder for myself...)*

Lastly, to demo calling ToolButtonGroup, I have a container component **starterContainer.js** that creates two tool button groups:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ToolButtonGroup from 'ToolButtonGroup';

// Import CSS for this App
import './starterContainer.css';

class StarterApp extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pitchersOrHitters: "",
            position: ""
        }
    }

    // Button and Select Handlers!
    handlePitchHitChange = (pitchersOrHitters) => {
        this.setState({pitchersOrHitters})
    }
    handlePositionChange = (position) => {
        this.setState({ position: position });
    }

    render() {

        // 0. Load State and Props 
        const { pitchersOrHitters, position } = this.state;


        // Pitcher or Hitter Radio Button Group params
        const pitchOrHitButtonGroup = {
            borderRadius: "25px",
            margin: "1% 10%",
            padding: "5%",
            fontsize: "2em",
            border: "2px solid #BBB",

            gridColumns: 1, minRowHeight: "10px", "gridID": "buttons1",

            header: "Choose One:",          
            buttons: [
                { value: "Pitchers", label: "Pitchers" },
                { value: "Hitters", label: "Hitters" },
            ],
            initialVal: "Pitchers"}

        // Pitcher or Hitter Radio Button Group params
        const positionButtonGroup = {
            borderRadius: "10px",
            margin: "1% 10%",
            padding: "5%",
            fontsize: "1.25em",
            border: "2px solid #BBB",

            gridColumns: 4, minRowHeight: "20px", "gridID": "buttons2",

            header: "Choose One:",          
            buttons: [
                { value: "SP", label: "SP" },
                { value: "RP", label: "RP" },
                { value: "1B", label: "1B" },
                { value: "2B", label: "2B" },
                { value: "SS", label: "SS" },
                { value: "3B", label: "3B" },
                { value: "LF", label: "LF" },
                { value: "RF", label: "RF" },
                { value: "CF", label: "CF" }
            ],
            initialVal: "SP"}


        return(
            <div className="chart-grid-container">
                <ToolButtonGroup
                    params={pitchOrHitButtonGroup}
                    value={pitchersOrHitters}
                    handler={this.handlePitchHitChange} />    

                <ToolButtonGroup
                    params={positionButtonGroup}
                    value={position}
                    handler={this.handlePositionChange} />    
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The only additional is a css grid for the layout of buttongroup and other components. This grid for the staterContainer will have many other components in here as well, including Select widgets and other widget components, as well as components that plot D3 graphs themselves. At first, this starterComponent css grid seems useless, but it will be helpful for my pages later on and I'd like to keep it.

**starterComponent.css**

```
.chart-grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
    grid-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-areas:
        "btns1 btns1 btns2 btns2 btns2 btns2 . . . . . .";
}

#buttons1 { grid-area: btns1; }     
#buttons2 { grid-area: btns2; }
```

With this, I have a few questions / issues:

[image]
[image]

**1. Bug:**  When my component initially loads, the ToggleButtons are hanging outside of the border designated in the parent container for the CSS grid. However, when I click any of the buttons, the ToggleButtons resize to fit inside of the grid container. I figure this is happening due to some formatting miscommunication between the two components, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

2. My handleChartTypeChange function isn't doing anything since I'm passing the this.props.handler directly to the ToggleButtonGroup. Can i get rid of handlechartTypeChange? Or should I use it still?
3. My starterContainer has 2 handle change functions... is there an easy way to turn this into 1 handle change function? This seems duplicative, and I may have more than 2 button groups on a page too.
4. In general, as a component that will be used in most of my apps and one that will have an important functionality, I want to make sure I'm creating it correctly. Are there any egregious React principles / CSS formatting approaches that
5. I am passing the initial values to my button groups **twice** - once in the parameters passed to the ToolButtonGroup component, and once as an initial state in the starterComponent as well. How can i remove this duplication?

Any help is appreciated - this is an important component for me to get correct for a web app of graphing tools that I am creating. If it's functionality is not working correctly, I'm going to have issues elsewhere for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The bulk of your questions might be more for [codereview.stack](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) but I have a few thoughts on it.

1.
Not a grid-master yet, but the direct child of the grid (container element with class "chart-grid-container") is an element with class "buttons-container". Right off the bat you have to wonder what if anything is defined under that css class. Second observation, with a glance [at this doc page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Grid_Template_Areas), is that you are missing the `grid-area` rule and I wonder if "gridID" prop is meant to match up with that.

2.
If you expect additional local logic will be added to that handler later on, yea keep it. Otherwise you don't need it.

3.
I actually like for clarity's sake that each has its own discrete named handler. On the other hand if there are a whole bunch of those components and repeating logic I would probably use es6 Object's dynamic prop names with thunk e.g.:

```
    // pseudo code!
    handleChange = (key_name) => {
      return (new_value) =>
        this.setState({
          [key_name]: new_value
        })
    }

   // later ...
   handler={this.handleChange('position')} />
```

4.
For your `ToolButtonGroup` component, if its not gonna carry its own local state, you should just [make it a function](https://javascriptplayground.com/functional-stateless-components-react/) in the case that the constructor and handler wrapper are not needed (as discussed above)

A second observation, is it necessary to have the props all passed in under another namespace ("params")? It doesn't seem to serve any purpose. I do think its neat that you are specifying the props for each component instance in its own object but what I would do next is just spread them into the JSX and then reference them directly off `this.props` [as outlined here](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html).

```
           <ToolButtonGroup
                {...positionButtonGroupProps}
                handler={this.handleChange('position')} />
```

5.
I am a little unclear on this question because I actually don't spot the `value` prop being referenced in `ToolButtonGroup`? Maybe I glossed over it. Anyway I would just attach that to the props object as described above

Comment: appreciate the feedback on this :)